# Python error messages including "ImportError: cannot import name 'string_int_label_map_pb2'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, object-detection

So I have been trying to get a captcha solver I found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tSrLELxq4YMn1-whRQ5yvU4Ns7n61MPQ/view) to work for quite some time now. I have fixed many weird problems with that time, but I honestly don't know what's wrong this time. So I am starting the program and I get some error messages. I am using python 3.6.2 and tensorflow 1.15 for this and this is the whole message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Linus\Desktop\captcha solver\main_.py", line 1, in <module>
    from CAPTCHA_object_detection import *
  File "C:\Users\Linus\Desktop\captcha solver\CAPTCHA_object_detection.py", line 19, in <module>
    from object_detection.utils import label_map_util
  File "C:\Users\Linus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\object_detection\utils\label_map_util.py", line 21, in <module>
    from object_detection.protos import string_int_label_map_pb2
ImportError: cannot import name 'string_int_label_map_pb2'
```

I have been focusing on the last line `from object_detection.protos import string_int_label_map_`
I think there is a stackoverflow regarding this last line already, but I have been trying to fix this in different ways already. I somehow came to the idea of installing protoc but ig the installation didn't even work. Can someone help me and/or bring me on the right track? I guess I should also mention that I am quite new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Read through the answer, few them contains step to step guide on installing protoc,many useful answers on issues thread.
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/1595